# How to change the links in top menu based on login status?

Tags: wordpress

Can someone please answere the question how can I change the top menu item's link based on login status? e.g. if you're not logged it, you'll see /register link, if you're logged in you'll get # link of even (if this item is root) you will see the list of subpages for that menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hard coding the links yourself, do something like this.

```
if(is_user_logged_in() ){
    echo '<a href="/">home</a>';
}else{
     echo '<a href="/register">register</a>';
}
```

Comment: thanks, but where's the file to edit? I'm not familiar with WP at all

Comment: `<!-- Start of topmenu -->` ? i'm not sure i can go that way, my menu link is in the middle of the menu, also it has subpages (overlaying menu) that I can't lose

Comment: @KennyPowers this solution is only if you hand code the links by yourself!

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing in my site like this.

### step 1: create of two menu's position

You have to create two menu position like this

```
function register_my_menus(){
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'new_user_navigation'=>__('New User Navigation'),
            'registered_user_navigation'=>__('Registered Navigation'),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init','register_my_menus' );
```

Place the above code in function.php file.
now this will create two navigation areas in your admin panel menu section. From ware you can select the menu to be shown under these navigation areas in front panel.

[image]

### Step 2: Select the menu from admin panel.

Now select the menu to be shown in particulate menu position.

### Step 3: Edit the code in header.php file.

Now by using @In God I Trust code you can let the WordPress decide which menu to be displayed when the user in logged in like this.

```
if(is_user_logged_in() ){
    if ( has_nav_menu( 'registered_user_navigation' ) ){
        wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'registered_user_navigation',
            'menu_item' => 'object_id'
        ) );
    } 
}else{
    if ( has_nav_menu( 'new_user_navigation' ) ){
        wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'new_user_navigation',
            'menu_item' => 'object_id'
        ) );
    } 
}
```